# What does "mustache twirly" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

I was watching an interview where a person was described using the following words.

> mustache twirly in his personality

What does *mustache twirl* / *mustache twirly* mean? Is it a symbol for something?

The described person is a bad person.

Answer (score 14):

"mustache twirly" (which should really be written as **mustache-twirly**) is a reference to stereotypical movie and cartoon villains like [Snidely Whiplash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snidely_Whiplash), who had a mustache that he liked to twirl while he gloated about his evil plans.  [The idea of mustache-twirling signifying a sneering villain is now a common one.](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DastardlyWhiplash?from=Main.MoustacheTwirlingVillain)

[image]

Comment: In my country it should 'really be written' as **moustache-twirly**.

Comment: Surely that's Dick Dastardly, rather than Snidely Whiplash.

Comment: Dick Dastardly indeed